# Numerical calculation of Lyapunov exponents without Jacobian

Tags: numerical-methods, matlab, chaos-theory

I have a numerical model that I would like to calculate the Lyapunov spectrum for. The number of dimensions is in the hundreds, and I don’t have an analytical expression for the Jacobian available. The system is chaotic (positive largest Lyapunov exponent) and the fractal dimension is not huge (3–5). The numerical integration is done with an explicit Euler method.

What would be the best/simplest way to calculate the full spectrum of Lyapunov exponents? Does anyone know of Matlab scripts I could use and/or adapt? My goal is to calculate the Kaplan–Yorke dimension, and determine if the system is hyperchaotic.

Comment: *The numerical integration is Euler explicit.* – Note that unless you have some very good reason for this, your life will be better if you choose an adaptive higher-order Runge–Kutta procedure, which you can find readily implemented in any reasonable programming language for scientific computing and also in Matlab.

Comment: Blatant self-advertisement: I wrote [a Python module](https://github.com/neurophysik/jitcode) that is targetted specifically as cases such as yours. Its advantages include: 1) It is optimised for quickly integrating high-dimensional systems. 2) It computes Lyapunov exponents almost automatically (including determining the Jacobian symbolically and doing orthonormalisations). 3) You can divert almost all blame on me by citation. 4) No Matlab.

Comment: As a reference to other methods and approaches: [this](https://arxiv.org/pdf/0811.0882.pdf).

Answer (score 2):

You almost certainly do not want the entire Lyapunov spectrum, but only the largest two, three, or maybe four Lyapunov exponents.
Strictly speaking, two suffice to show hyperchaos, but you may want to go for the first zero one as a sanity check.
Getting, say, the hundredth Lyapunov exponent requires a lot of computation time and your result will likely be very inaccurate.
Most importantly, you do not gain anything from it.
You do not need it for the Kaplan–Yorke dimension either.

That being said, if you do not want to work with the Jacobian, orbit separation is the way to go.
More specifically, you integrate many slightly different versions of the system and observe how their separation (the Lyapunov vectors) evolves.
For Lyapunov exponents beyond the first one, you have to take care to regularly remove any components in the direction of the previous Lyapunov vectors.

Technically, the procedure for the first two Lyapunov exponents is:

1. Select some parameters $ε$, representing the size of a small perturbation, and $τ$ representing the rescaling interval. For most systems, $ε=10^{-12}$ is a good choice. Use a handful of oscillations of your dynamics for $τ$, but more about this choice later.
2. Create three instances of your system, and call denote their states at time $t$ by $y_0(t)$, $y_1(t)$, and $y_2(t)$.
3. Set the initial condition $y_0(0)$ to something on the attractor. Set $y_1(0)=y_0(0) +ε·r_1$ and $y_2(0)=y_0(0) +ε·r_2$, where $r_1$ and $r_2$ are random vectors.
4. Integrate for $τ$ time units.
5. Compute
   $$ v_1(t) = \frac{y_1(t)-y_0(t)}{|y_1(t)-y_0(t)|};
    \qquad λ_1(t) = \frac{1}{τ}\log \left( \frac{|y_1(t)-y_0(t)|}{ε} \right).$$

   $v_1$ is your first Lyapunov vector.
   $λ_1$ is your first local Lyapunov exponent.
   If $|y_1(t)-y_0(t)|$ is not much smaller than your attractor’s diameter, your choice of $τ$ is too high.
6. Compute
   $$ v_2(t) = \frac{y_2(t)-y_0(t)-\langle y_2, v_1 \rangle v_1}{\left | y_2(t)-y_0(t)-\langle y_2, v_1 \rangle v_1 \right|};
    \qquad λ_2(t) = \frac{1}{τ} \log \left(\frac{\left| y_2(t)-y_0(t)-\langle y_2, v_1 \rangle v_1 \right|}{ε} \right).$$

   $v_2$ is your second Lyapunov vector.
   $λ_2$ is your second local Lyapunov exponent.
   Note how this is analogous to Step 5 except for removing the projection on $v_1$.
7. Set $y_1(t) = y_0(t) + εv_1(t)$ and $y_2(t) = y_0(t) + εv_2(t)$. This *rescaling* is to ensure that your separations stay small.
8. Go to step 4.

After this you can average the $λ_1$ and $λ_2$ (except the first few ones) to obtain the respective Lyapunov exponents.

You could also estimate the Jacobian from finite differences, but that’s just replacing one $ε$ with another.

Comment: Thanks! Clearly explained, but I tried this on the Rossler hyperchaotic system and got garbage results (negative lambda 1, positive lambda 2). Are you sure the equation for the lyapunov exponents is correct? I don't see how it lines up with the typical definition of the lyapunov exponent.

Comment: @Llouis: I double-checked everything and indeed found a mistake (dividing by τ before taking the logarithm). I also added some explanations. Either way, I strongly recommend to understand the concept of this approach rather than blindly implementing the algorithm.

Comment: Thanks! I'm wondering: in the log, should it be what you wrote over epsilon (the initial separation distance)? I'm getting a reasonable (off by a mysterious few %) lambda_1 that way, but my lambda_2 is way too big.  I notice the algorithm you describe is similar to Wolf et al. 1984 (https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/0167278985900119), but that method involves the Jacobian. Do you know of any references for the orbit separation method you describe that don't involve analytically linearizing the equations? I tried googling e.g. "orbit separation lyapunov" but I don't find much.

Comment: @Llouis: *in the log, should it be what you wrote over epsilon (the initial separation distance)?* – Yes, indeed. I really managed to botch this. — *I notice the algorithm you describe is similar to Wolf et al. 1984 […], but that method involves the Jacobian.* – Note that Wolf’s method is made for experimental data, so it’s overkill in your case. It also does not use the Jacobian, IIRC. — I may look for references on classical orbit separation later.

Comment: I meant the algorithm presented in section 3 of that paper, not the one from section 4. I could try the section 4 method, but Wolf cautions against using it for high-dimensional systems.

Comment: *I meant the algorithm presented in section 3 of that paper,* – Yeah, that’s just a rehashing of the standard Jacobian-based methods (Bennetin and Shimada–Nagashima), so exactly what you do not want.

Comment: @Llouis: As for a reference for the orbit-separation method for more than one Lyapunov exponent, it’s indeed hard to find. If [the paper linked by Evgeny](https://arxiv.org/pdf/0811.0882.pdf) is to be trusted, people did tangent-space methods (i.e., needing the Jacobian) pretty much at the same time as they did more than one Lyapunov exponent. Still, it’s straightforward if you translate the tangent-space method for more than one Lyapunov exponent back to orbit-separation methods. (You can find a description of orbit separation [here](https://doi.org/10.1103/PhysRevA.14.2338).)